# setText method gives random output

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, textview

I have weird issue with my Textview inside recyclerview.

Recyclerview item

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventName"
        android:text="@string/lorem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventDate"
        android:text="@string/lorem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventAlarm"
        android:text="@string/lorem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/eventDelete"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/alarmIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/eventDelete"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/eventDelete"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_notifications_24"

        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/eventDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventDate"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_24"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/newEventLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/newEventLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/name_hint"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/timePicker1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selectedDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/selected_date"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/datePicker"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/datePicker" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="selectDate"
            android:text="@string/select_date"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addCounter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:onClick="newCountdown"
            android:text="@string/add_10_countdown"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/datePicker"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/alarmSwitch" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/alarmSwitch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/alarm"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/datePicker"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/selectedDate" />

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker1"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:timePickerMode="spinner"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/datePicker"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

my model of event

```
package com.example.countdowntimer.model;

import java.util.Date;

public class Event {

    String name;
    Date date;
    Boolean alarm;

    public Event(String name, Date date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Event(String name, Date date, boolean alarm) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
        this.alarm = alarm;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Boolean getAlarm() {
        return alarm;
    }

    public void setAlarm(Boolean alarm) {
        this.alarm = alarm;
    }
}
```

Main activity

```
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat;
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.countdowntimer.adapter.Adapter;
import com.example.countdowntimer.model.Event;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    EditText eventName;
    Button datePicker, addCounter;
    SwitchCompat alarmSwitch;
    TimePicker timePicker;
    ArrayList<Event> eventArrayList;
    Calendar newDate;
    TextView selectedDate;
    Adapter adapter;
    private static MainActivity instance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //just findviewsbyid
        findViews();
        //load eventArraylist from sharedpreferences
        loadData();
        //set clock for 24h mode and starting time at 12:00
        setTimePicker();
        adapter = new Adapter(eventArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        instance = this;
        

    }

    public void newCountdown(View view) {
        String name = eventName.getText().toString();
        if(name.isEmpty())
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Warning")
                    .setMessage("Please specyfiy name")
                    .setNegativeButton("ok", null)
                    .show();
            eventName.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));

        }
        if(newDate == null){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Warning")
                    .setMessage("Please specyfiy date")
                    .setNegativeButton("ok", null)
                    .show();
            datePicker.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
        }
        if(!name.isEmpty() && newDate != null){
            newDate.getTime();
            newDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getHour());
            newDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getMinute());
            Event event = new Event(name, newDate.getTime(), alarmSwitch.isChecked());
            eventArrayList.add(eventArrayList.size(), event);
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(eventArrayList.size());
            saveData();
            hideKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
            eventName.setHintTextColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),R.color.black, null));
            datePicker.setHintTextColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),R.color.white, null));

        }
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void selectDate(View view) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        final DatePickerDialog startTime = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int y, int m, int d) {
                newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(y,m,d);
                selectedDate.setText(d + "-" +m + "-" + y);
            }
        },calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        startTime.show();
    }


    private void findViews() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        eventName = findViewById(R.id.name);
        datePicker = findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        addCounter = findViewById(R.id.addCounter);
        alarmSwitch = findViewById(R.id.alarmSwitch);
        timePicker = findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        selectedDate = findViewById(R.id.selectedDate);
        eventArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void setTimePicker() {
        timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
        timePicker.setHour(12);
        timePicker.setMinute(0);
    }

    public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
        if (view == null) {
            view = new View(activity);
        }
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    public void saveData(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("List storage", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        //put list of events in here
        String json = gson.toJson(eventArrayList);
        editor.putString("Events list", json);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private void loadData(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("List storage", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("Events list", null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Event>>() {}.getType();
        eventArrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        if(eventArrayList == null)
        {
            eventArrayList = new ArrayList<Event>();
        }
    }

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }


}
```

```
package com.example.countdowntimer.adapter;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.countdowntimer.MainActivity;
import com.example.countdowntimer.R;
import com.example.countdowntimer.model.Event;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Event> eventArrayList;
    TextView eventName;
    TextView eventDate;
    TextView eventAlarm;
    ImageButton eventDelete;
    ImageView alarmIcon;
    Drawable alarmOn;
    Drawable alarmOff;


    //simple constructor
    public Adapter(ArrayList<Event> eventArrayList) {
        this.eventArrayList = eventArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    //we inflate view from layout file
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_countdown_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    //bind data here
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Event event = eventArrayList.get(position);
        eventName.setText(event.getName());
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(event.getDate());
        String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm").format(event.getDate());
        eventDate.setText(date);
        eventAlarm.setText("Time: "+ time);
        if(event.getAlarm()!=null){
            if(event.getAlarm()){
                alarmIcon.setImageDrawable(alarmOn);
            }else {
                alarmIcon.setImageDrawable(alarmOff);

            }
        }






    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return eventArrayList.size();
    }



    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            eventName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventName);
            eventDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventDate);
            eventAlarm = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventAlarm);
            eventDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventDelete);
            alarmIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alarmIcon);
            alarmOn = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(itemView.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications_24, null);
            alarmOff = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(itemView.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications_off_24, null);
            eventDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                //TODO some warning before removal
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    eventArrayList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                    MainActivity.getInstance().saveData();
                }
            });


        }
    }
}
```

So when I create new event using the same name I get some random values inside eventName textview (after few new objects or sometimes even as first or second one). As you notice i store those objects in shared preferences so when i restart my app names are corrected which makes me confused. I tried to debug it and find where does it goes wrong but each steps looks fine.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/KzI0Nah Simple example, i cleared list and added few objects name "qwert" but somehow they got named "dhhdgfxf"

Comment: It seem you are not removing the arraylist data from MainActivity class. Instead you're just updating the adapter data only. This is obvious what you're getting the output.

Comment: arraylist data removal is handled in recycler viewholder at least that was my intention with eventArrayList.remove(getAdapterPosition());

Comment: Better if you try with local database instead of SharedPreference. I recommend you to use Jetpack and architectural component to clean code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
adapter.notifyItemInserted(eventArrayList.size());
```

replace to

```
adapter.notifyItemInserted(eventArrayList.size() - 1);
```

Last position of arraylist equals size - 1

Upd. And it:

```
 eventArrayList.add(eventArrayList.size(), event);
```

may replace to

```
 eventArrayList.add(event);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. I applied both of those updates but problem persist

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out, what's exactly is going wrong. Like I cleared whole list then added 3 objects named "qwe", then another 3 named "qwaz", next I removed last 3 objects and added 3 named "qwazt". First was fine but second and third was suddenly named "qwaz". That is some kind of hint but I guess it will take a while for me to find an error